# A UIImagePickerController story: how to grab the image for insert in a tweet?

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I have to add an image in a tweet. I tried this code, and only the picker shows. When I tap on the image it doesn't grab... Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)sendImageTweet:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [tweetViewController addImage:(UIImage *)image];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks, and sorry for my English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are dismissing a viewController and presenting one at the same time. I did this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[self performSelector: @selector(showTweetwithPhoto:) withObject: image afterDelay: 0.5];

}
```

and it worked perfectly

```
-(void) showTweetwithPhoto:(UIImage*)image {
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetViewController addImage:image];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the image data (returned by UIImagePickerController) to UIImage object, as shown below. (I have changed 2nd line of your code).

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage*)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage * image = (UIImage *) [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```